# Using FullCalendar for the first time

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I hope this is not a stupid question/issue. I am trying to use fullcalendar for the first time. I am running this from flask on a local server. Here is the code I am attempting to use, based on examples I have found from some googling:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

So when I run that, it just gives me nothing.Am I missing a resource?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/87bpo8p5/ - You probably want to move at least the onload script to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You never load the fullcalendar into the div. Do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This way you load it as soon as the document is ready.

Answer (score -1):

Can you check your css link? I think It should end with fullcalendar.min.css not fullcalednar.min.css.